# In order execution with TBB?

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

I would like to have something like a [`tbb::task_group`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/index.htm#reference/reference.htm) but with the difference of guaranteed in order execution, e.g.

```
serial_task_group tasks;

tasks.run([]{std::cout << 1;});
tasks.run([]{std::cout << 2;});
tasks.run([]{std::cout << 3;});
tasks.wait();

// guaranteed output: 123
```

Any suggestions as to how one could achieve this using tbb?

Currently I have an explicit thread that just executes from a queue using a condition variable. However, the problem with using a queue is how I would go about guaranteeing 
 that only exactly one task is active in the task_group.

Comment: I can't really see what you are trying to archieve. If I understand it correctly you want only tasks to be executed in order and only one at a time. But in this case I don't see what you need the `task_group` for. If you don't have concurrent execution, you could just do whatever you need to directly in the calling thread/function instead of delegating to a `task`-structure. And regarding the last part of your question: How would more then one task be active at a time, if you have only one thread executing tasks?

Comment: @Grizzly: I have a lot of other concurrent stuff going on. However, the particular computation I want to run here need to be run in order and are very heavy. If I use an explicit thread, instead of using the task-scheduler, I have quite an overhead due to oversubscription. My goal here is to run everything in the task-scheduler.

Comment: Have you looked at tbb flow graph? On windows the agents library does this easily, in tbb flow graph is the closest equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Disclosure: I work on Intel Threading Building Blocks at Intel.)

As was suggested in another answer, you can use the flow graph to do something like this.  The code for your example using the flow graph would look something like:

```
#include "tbb/flow_graph.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace tbb::flow;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    graph g;
    continue_node< continue_msg > n1( g, []( const continue_msg & ) { std::cout << "1"; } );
    continue_node< continue_msg > n2( g, []( const continue_msg & ) { std::cout << "2"; } );
    continue_node< continue_msg > n3( g, []( const continue_msg & ) { std::cout << "3"; } );
    make_edge( n1, n2 );
    make_edge( n2, n3 );
    n1.try_put( continue_msg() );
    g.wait_for_all();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, but based on what you posted, maybe this, http://pastebin.com/i2rxGKsP?

Comment: Yes this should work.  Since the node is serial it will receive and execute the functions in order, never overlapping their execution.  And they will be scheduled as TBB tasks and so will be able to execute concurrently with any other TBB tasks in the system.

Comment: There must be a simpler method than having to create an object for every task to be executed in parallel -- this may not be feasible or fully unnecessary.